# Apache-ODE ProcessManagement

Tags: apache-axis, apache-ode

I can access this API/WS through
`http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/ProcessManagement?wsdl`.

1. I would like to get the Process Info of a Process through this service and active it.
   The serivce has the matching operations `getProcessInfo` and activate.
   With `listAllProcesses` I get all Processes of a delpoyed package.
   For `getProcessInfo/activate` I need the Process `pid`.
   I get a `<ns:pid>`, using this gets me a load of Exceptions.
   Using the name of the process and other stuff I receive earlier doesn't work either.
   The `pid` is of type `QName`, perhaps thats the root of the problem.
   However I don't now how to typecast here.
   (Tried all with the eclipse Web Services Explorer and soapUI)

   **question:** How does a proper request for both Operations look like?
2. When I try to consume the webservice with axi2 via eclipse, there is a undeclared variable `local` in the AnySimpleType class. I'm not keen on using the service this way.
   But since I'm already writing a Client for the DeploymentService I thought about this approach.

   **question:** How do I properly access the ProcessManagement?

EDIT: I have a simular problem with the [DeploymentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621738/apache-ode-bpel-deployment-with-a-webservice-file-transfer) and the `undeploy` Operation.
EDIT2: I figured the Problem with the DeploymentService `undeploy` out.
I had to get the Packagename as String. Then a made a javax.xml.namespace.QName out of it. Then I used the `setPackageName` of said `undeploy` operation.

**Answer** to question number 1:
soapUI with listAllProcesses returns
`<ns:pid>{ode/bpel/unit-test}HelloWorld2-1</ns:pid>`
getProcessInfo wants

```
<pmap:getProcessInfo>
    <pid>?</pid>
</pmap:getProcessInfo>
```

Now I replaced `<pid>?</pid>` with
`<pid xmlns:odetest="http://ode/bpel/unit-test">odetest:HelloWorld2-1</pid>`
and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember that there was an issue with parameter ordering when using the Axis2 generated WSDL. Could you try if building a request against the original WSDL located at `http://localhost:8080/ode/deployment/services/ProcessManagement` works?

**EDIT:** Now that I got the question correctly, the problem is that ODE expects the QName to be serialized differently, i.e. in the XML way instead of the Java way. Thus, instead of `<ns:pid>{ode/bpel/unit-test}HelloWorld2-1</ns:pid>` the correct notation is `<ns:pid xmlns:odetest="ode/bpel/unit-test">odetest:HelloWorld2-1</ns:pid>`.

Comment: I still can't forge a valid request for getProcessInfo and if I try to let eclipse and axis2 do its magic, it's even worse. No code at all will be generated and I get the following error:Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: An imported schema was announced to have the namespace http://www.apache.org/ode/pmapi/types/2006/08/02/, but has the namespace null

Comment: In soapUI I do the following steps: listAllProcesses, which gives me a list of my processes. I have i.e. <ns:pid>{http://ode/bpel/unit-test}HelloWorld2-1</ns:pid> now I try to get the process info with getProcessInfo with this pid. I only receive a load of errors. What is wrong with my `<pid>`?

Comment: Ah, please try to use a "real" QName and not its java serialization. So instead of ```<ns:pid>{ode/bpel/unit-test}HelloWorld2-1</ns:pid>``` I think it should read ```<ns:pid xmlns:odetest="ode/bpel/unit-test">odetest:HelloWorld2-1</ns:pid>```

Comment: Since I can't import the service with axis2, I'm using soapUI. The `<soapenv:Body>` looks like this `<pmap:getProcessInfo><pid>?</pid></pmap:getProcessInfo>`. The pid is not ns:pid like I get from the listAllProcesses. So I still receive loads of errors.

Comment: What you suggested was nearly right, there was a http:// missing. I replaced the `<pid></pid>` with `<pid xmlns:odetest="http://ode/bpel/unit-test">odetest:HelloWorld2-1</pid>` that worked. Unfortunately that's only soapUI.

Comment: I just realised that activating a process doesn't start it, I don't need the ProcessManagement anymore. So nevermind the axis2 import problem. But I still have the problem with DeploymentService `undeploy`

Comment: I also figured the `undeploy` Problem out (see edit). Thank you. Do you wanna edit your answer or should I accept it anyway? Do you have any suggestions to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858380/parse-bpel-file-to-extract-activities-xpath#comment19217870_13858380 ?

Comment: Regarding the missing http://, I took that from your example, which didnt have the http:// in the namespace. I edited my answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: You're right. That is weird that got lost somewhere. Thank you.